# How to know which commands are executed when I do something in GUI

Tags: linux, process, monitoring, architecture

This is for academic purpose. I want to know which commands are executed when we do something in GUI, for example creating a folder. I want to show that both the `mkdir` shell command and `create folder` option from GUI does the same thing.

Comment: Use strace to see what system calls are being performed.

Comment: and the thing is that the "create folder" option will probably *not* call `mkdir` (the command) but the `mkdir()` system function. This depends a *lot* on the GUI tool you use to do things, but I'd expect many of those to use system calls instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can observe what the process does with the [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) command. Strace shows the [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) performed by a process. Everything¹ a process that affects its environment is done through system calls. For example, creating a directory can only be done by ultimately calling the [`mkdir` system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir). The [`mkdir` shell command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir) is a thin wrapper around the system call of the same name.

To see what `mkdir` is doing, run

```
strace mkdir foo
```

You'll see a lot of calls other than `mkdir` (76 in total for a successful `mkdir` on my system), starting with [`execve`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) which loads the process binary image, then calls to load the libraries and data files used by the program, calls to allocate memory, calls to observe the system state, … Finally the command calls `mkdir` and wraps down, finishing with [`exit_group`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/exit_group).

To observe what a GUI program is doing, start it and only observe it during one action. Find out the process ID of the program (with `ps x`, `htop` or any other process viewer), then run

```
strace -o file_manager.mkdir.strace -p1234
```

This puts the trace from process 1234 in the file `file_manager.mkdir.strace`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop `strace` without stopping the program. Note that something like entering the name of the directory may involve thousands or tens of thousands of system calls: handling mouse movements, focus changes and so on is a lot more complex at that level than creating a directory.

You can select what system calls are recorded in the `strace` output by passing the `-e` option. For example, to omit `read`, `write` and `select`:

```
strace -e \!read,write,select …
```

To only record `mkdir` calls:

```
strace -e mkdir …
```

¹  <sub>Ok, almost everything. Shared memory only involves a system call for the initial setup.</sub>

Comment: Cool answer, thanks for sharing the knowledge.